# Creating default object from empty value "error in laravel"

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

Hi I'm working on update products form of e-commerce site but when I try to edit details then it shows error "Undefined variable: fileName" and error line is:

```php
 Product::where(['id'=>$id])->
 update(['product_name'=>$data['product_name'],
 'product_code'=>$data['product_ code'],
 'product_color'=>$data['product_color'],
 'description'=>$data['description'],
 'price'=>$data['price'],'image'=>$fileName]);
    return redirect()->back()->with('flash_message_success','Product 
  updated successfully!');
```

or when i try to update image only then its error is: "Creating default object from empty value", or error line is:

```php
$product->image = $filename;
```

this is code of ProductsController:

```php
 public function editProduct(Request $request, $id=null){

  if($request->isMethod('post')){
    $data = $request->all();
    //echo "<pre>"; print_r($data); die;


    if($request->hasFile('image')){
      $image_tmp = Input::file('image');
      if($image_tmp->isValid()){
        $extension = $image_tmp->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $filename = rand(111,99999).'.'.$extension;
        $large_image_path = 
  'images/backend_images/products/large/'.$filename;
        $medium_image_path = 
  'images/backend_images/products/medium/'.$filename;
        $small_image_path = 
  'images/backend_images/products/small/'.$filename;
        // Resize Images
        Image::make($image_tmp)->save($large_image_path);
        Image::make($image_tmp)->resize(600,600)->save($medium_image_path);
        Image::make($image_tmp)->resize(300,300)->save($small_image_path);

        // Store image name in products table
        $product->image = $filename;
       }
      }

     if(empty($data['description'])){
          $data['description'] = '';
        }


     Product::where(['id'=>$id])- 
      >update(['product_name'=>$data['product_name'],
       'product_code'=>$data['product_code'],
       'product_color'=>$data['product_color'],
       'description'=>$data['description'],
       'price'=>$data['price'],'image'=>$fileName]);
       return redirect()->back()->with('flash_message_success','Product 
        updated successfully!');
       }

    //Get product details
    $productDetails = Product::where(['id'=>$id])->first();

     return view('admin.products.edit_product')- 
      >with(compact('productDetails'));
    }
```

Comment: You're not defining `$product` anywhere, but then promptly trying to use it in your code via `$product->image = $filename`

Comment: @TimLewis would u prefer to tell me how to resolve it

Comment: Define `$product` as something before you try to set a property... Like `$product = ...;` then `$product->image ...`

Comment: $product = $filename; but still same error

Answer (score 0):

"Undefined variable: fileName"

There's a typo in your variable. Change `$fileName` to `$filename`.

Answer (score 0):

i guess you need to do something like this

```
$product=new Product();
$product->image = $filename;
```

also where did you define $fileName in your code?

Comment: please what is the error, if possible post the screenshot